# I need a clarification about dependencies

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

What is the difference between:

```
myApp.controller('GreetingController',     ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

And

```
   myApp.controller('GreetingController',      function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
});
```

Some of the examples add dependency for scope and some are not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your samples have a scope dependency injected, the difference being the first one uses the array notation which allows you to create custom naming, won't break when minifying, etc... It's the recommended way. For example, this works fine:

```
myApp.controller('GreetingController',     ['$scope', function(myScopeAlias) {
  myScopeAlias.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

---

See it in action here:

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function(myScopeAlias) {
      myScopeAlias.greeting = 'Hola!';
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="GreetingController">{{greeting}}</div>
```

---

> Dependency Annotation
>
> Angular invokes certain functions (like service factories and controllers) via the injector. You need to annotate these functions so that the injector knows what services to inject into the function. There are three ways of annotating your code with service name information:

- Using the inline array annotation (preferred)
- Using the $inject property annotation
- Implicitly from the function parameter names (has caveats)

Read more: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation

Comment: Note that in strict DI mode (which is enabled by adding `ng-strict-di` directive on the same element as ng-app) angular throws an error whenever a service tries to use implicit annotation for dependency injection.

Comment: @joelkornbluh Yes, it's in the Read More link I provided. Didn't want to quote too much from it.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to emphasis one point:

Always using the inline array annotation if you project need to do the Uglification(Most real project need a uglification).

[Building minification-safe Angular.js applications](http://thegreenpizza.github.io/2013/05/25/building-minification-safe-angular.js-applications/)